# Combine two pandas dataframes of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'd like to take 2 separate dataframes, each comprised of a bunch of dictionaries, and combine them to yield the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[{'a':1}, {'a':2}]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[{'b':1}, {'b':2}]])
df3 = pd.some_function(df1, df2)
```

where `pd.some_function` takes the two dfs and performs a cell-wise merge of the dictionaries:

```
                    0                   1
0  {u'a': 1, u'b': 1}  {u'a': 2, u'b': 2}
```

I know I can do this with a for loop, but is there a pandas function that can do this more succinctly?  Simply adding the dfs does not work.  I'm familiar with `df.applymap`, but my understanding is that will apply a function to each cell of a single df.

Comment: You want dictionaries stored as values in your DF? You know that this kinda defeats the point of pandas since you won't be able to apply vectorized operations?

Comment: Prior to making the dataframes, what does your data look like? Is it a list of dictionaries? I think you should make some transformation of the data before that step so you can optimise the representation ready for a DF.

Comment: Prior to making the dataframe, my data is a nested list of dictionaries. I realize it's a bit weird to turn this into a df, but for this particular application, I'm using the multiindex feature of pandas to help keep track of different levels of my data structure and to slice up the df into chunks for further analysis.

Comment: You could store them as a mutli-index dataframe, and then just merge

Comment: @Acccumulation could you please provide a code example? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `concat`+`ChainMap`

```
from collections import ChainMap


df=pd.concat([df1,df2])
df.groupby(df.index)[0,1].agg(lambda x :dict(ChainMap(*x.values.tolist())))
Out[94]: 
                  0                 1
0  {'b': 1, 'a': 1}  {'b': 2, 'a': 2}
```

Comment: I still can't help but think this really isn't what the OP wants to do, but isn't aware of the inefficiencies of storing dicts like this. Maybe I'm wrong; it's an elegant answer to achieve what was actually asked :)

Comment: @roganjosh thank you, his question confused me as well

Comment: @Wen thanks for your answer!  I think the question is pretty clear.  It's the way that I'm representing the data that may be confusing you, but see my comment to roganjosh above :)

Comment: @AndrewHeusser aha, got you , so is this what you need ?

Comment: I was hoping not to have to import the extra class and do this using pandas functions only, but this will work if it's not possible!  Thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewHeusser if only pandas, it will involve for loop , which is not you wanted : -)

Comment: @AndrewHeusser and collections is basic python lib , feel free to use it with any advance package